# Remove 'read more' link when post is shorter than excerpt

Tags: excerpt, read-more

How can I remove the 'read more' link from a post excerpt on a blog/archive page when there is nothing more to read...when the length of the post is shorter than the excerpt?

Comment: Are you using `the_content()` or `the_excerpt()` followed a hard coded read-more link in your archive template?

Comment: Show me your code of displaying the post excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `the_excerpt()` or `$post->post_excerpt`? Use `$post->post_excerpt` and count your words then if the limit exceeds show the read more otherwise don't show.